# Applying Bonferroni correction to eQTL analysis done with Matrix_eQTL_engine

Tags: r, bonferroni

I have completed an `eqtl` analysis using the `MatrixEQTL` package.

```r
me <- Matrix_eQTL_engine(
    snps = snps,
    gene = gene,
    cvrt = cvrt,
    output_file_name = output_file_name,
    pvOutputThreshold = 0.05,
    useModel = modelLINEAR, 
    errorCovariance = errorCovariance, 
    verbose = TRUE,
    pvalue.hist = TRUE,
    min.pv.by.genesnp = FALSE,
    noFDRsaveMemory = FALSE)
```

The code is taken from `?Matrix_eQTL_engine`, which also contains the code to set things up.

I set a threshold `pvalue` as `0.05` but I am wondering if there is a way to find a threshold value  by a test to include in this script. I also want to correct for multiple testing and as per `matrixeqtl` manual, it does correct for `False Discovery Rate`. But I want to find a threshold `pvalue` for multiple testing for `Bonferroni correction` and then used that `pvalue`. I hope to add that to this code as well. Thank you for any suggestion/help!

Comment: Please feel free to contact me directly regarding the package.
My contact email is in every page of the package reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the author of the package here.

First, I would NOT suggest using `pvOutputThreshold = 1` as it can result in storing billions of p-values and make R run out of memory.

Second, Matrix eQTL returns the number of tests it has conducted, so that you can do Bonferroni correction yourself. You can get it with this line:

```
me$all$ntests
```

or, if you differentiate local and distant tests:

```
me$cis$ntests
me$trans$ntests
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrey! Based on your suggestion, I  have calculated Bonferroni threshold. Does MatrixEQTL gives an option to choose any correction as I see it automatically gives FDR values for each association? How can I use this Bonferroni threshold to choose the corrected p values. Thank you!

Comment: Let's take a look at an example. Say, we have N = 1,000,000 tests. Then, after Bonferroni correction, a test is significant at 5% if p-value is < 0.05 / N. This is then the p-value threshold you can provide to Matrix eQTL.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I am trying to find ways to summarize/present (such as figures) eqtl findings here. Can you suggest some ways to get useful interpretations of the gene-SNP associations reported. Thank you!